# Does Doxygen support Background Images?

Tags: html, css, doxygen

I'm currently setting up doxygen to use for generating my project's documentation. I've included a few custom pages which include html code.

These html files use custom .css stylesheets for their backgrounds - which work fine in web browsers. In the doxygen output .chm file, all the text and images appear in their correct places (and use the correct font and sizes) - however the background image does not display.

Does Doxygen support background images - and if so do I have to change any settings to display the images?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my issue, here's how I did it:

The reason for doing all of these steps is because doxygen doesn't have a very obvious way of including images from .css files.

To compile the extra pages in .chm format:

1. Use doxygen to update the code changes to .chm format as normal.
2. Run a tool called "Keytools" (It's freeware: http://www.grainge.org/pages/authoring/reverse_engineering/KeyToolsSetup.zip )
3. Decompile the .chm to give a .hhp format.
4. Open the .hhp file in Microsoft's HTML Help program.
5. Import the contents folder in the Contents section.
6. Add all of the images used in the documentation .css file to the Project as Topic Files.
7. Add the html pages to the contents page.
8. Compile the .chm file.